# pygame window showing "not responding"

Tags: python, pygame

When I am running my pygame program the game window is showing not responding and I have also written quit function but I don't know why its again ad again showing not responding
and my laptop is windows 8 and 32-bit

```
    import pygame

#initializing pygame
pygame.init()

# create game screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg,(x,y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        # if keystroke is pressed check the weather its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.1 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.1
        
        # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
        # 5 = 5 + 0.1
        playerX += player_change
        player(playerX, playerY)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to update the display in the application loop, instead of the event loop.
Furthermore the name of the variable is `playerX_change` rather than `player_change` and when a key is released, you have to set `playerX_change = 0.0` instead of `playerX_change = 0.1`:

```py
running = True
while running:

    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        # if keystroke is pressed check the weather its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.1 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.0 # <---- 0.0 instead of 0.1


    #<--| INDENTATION
    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1
    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)

    pygame.display.update()
```